# Selenium ChromeDriver doesn't Navigate with --headless in console application c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

Good day to all! I have a problem using Selenium ChromeDriver in console application, i use code like this:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=G:\Data\ProfilesData\Profile1");

var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
```

Please help me understand so that the browser goes to the desired URL in the console application

I tried to remove the --headless parameter, the browser starts and goes to the desired page, this process does not work without visualization

Comment: which version of Selenium do you use? and which version of Chrome?

Comment: Hello Mahsum Akbas! I use 109.0.5414.7400, but I try last version 110.0.5481.7700 but no result

Comment: The application stops working on the line driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url), after which an error occurs - OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51728/session timed out after 60 seconds."

Comment: I think you miss the argument `profile-directory`. Try with `options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=G:\Data\ProfilesData")` and `options.AddArgument("profile-directory=Profile1")`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried this option, I specified the folder with profiles and the name of a specific profile, everything works on local hosting, it does not work on the server machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem in a blog post on the official website. Now you need to use option `--headless=new`, not `--headless`. The working code looks like this:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless=new");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=G:\Data\ProfilesData\Profile1");

var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
```

Comment: In my web api project using VS2022 and .net core7, it worked successfully without adding the the "user-data-dir" argument. What exactly is the purpose of adding this parameter?

Comment: Using profiles for sites

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in using the profile, when commenting out the line with connecting the profile everything works, I found a comment on one of the sites that says about a Chrome bug, it cannot work with a profile in headless mode. But everything works fine on my local machine, it doesn't work on the server machine. It is necessary to look for some settings of the server machine.